# Pinch Zoom in VS Code PDF Viewer?

Tags: 22.04, pdf, wayland, latex, installed-programs

After moving from Windows 11 to Ubuntu 22.04, I have been getting used to the new features, but something I am missing is using the trackpad to pinch to zoom in various applications.

One specific case is VS Code, where I write a lot of LaTeX documents. However, I no longer have the ability to use the trackpad to pinch zoom while viewing PDFs of those LaTeX documents in the native VS Code PDF viewer. I do have that ability in Evince, so was wondering if there's a way to enable pinch zoom in VS Code?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you mean, you want to pinch in the trackpad? Do you have a touch screen?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thank you for the clarifying question, I have edited my question to reflect it is an issue with using the pinch to zoom on a trackpad.

Comment: Mouse Wheel Zoom Ctrl+Wheel is available but not gesture yet.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka I see... thank you!